# I want to load a converte.d csv to json file document to elasticsearch using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, elasticsearch, kibana

I started my commands with the following, I don't know what is the next command shall I add to upload the document to elasticsearch using Powershell.

```
$j=import-csv "C:\Elastic\account.csv" 

$j.Count

$j.ForEach({ 
    Write-Host $_.userID
    $json_body = ConvertTo-Json $_
    Write-Host $json_body
})
```

Comment: You should probably also add some code that at least attempts to upload to the API in question. You should also add a link to the docs for the API in question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be something like:

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "http://yourAPI.address/api" -Body $json_body